# UPDATE SET FORMAT not working in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

FORMAT instruction works in a SELECT but has no effect in an UPDATE:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

[image]

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;
CREATE TABLE #t(DateMin datetime);
INSERT INTO #t VALUES ('2019-13-01 00:00:00')

SELECT * FROM #t
```

[image]

```
UPDATE #t SET DateMin = FORMAT(DateMin, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
SELECT * FROM #t;
```

[image]

```
SELECT @DateMin AS a, FORMAT(@DateMin, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS b
```

[image]

Comment: A datetime doesn't have a format. `FORMAT` returns a `nvarchar`, so that value is just implicitly converted back to the `datetime` value.

Comment: Your query actually is `UPDATE #t SET DateMin = CONVERT(datetime, FORMAT(DateMin, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));`. It converts the dates to strings and then parses them back to dates. The only effect that may have is corrupting the data in case the current default date format is not dd/mm.

Comment: I also recommend against the `FORMAT` function; although it looks like a great function it can be horrifically slow. If you do *need* to display a Date and Time datatype as a `(n)varchar` with a specific formatting, you'll find the [Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) for `CONVERT` far faster. But really, such thigns should be left to your presentation layer, and you should **never** store a date and time value as an `(n)varchar` in your RDBMS.

Comment: OK, I understand the issue is the UPDATE involves changing the column type dynamically, which cannot be done.

Comment: *"I understand the issue is the UPDATE involves changing the column type dynamically"* No, that isn't a problem with `UPDATE`. A column can only be one specific datatype, not many. In this case, `a` is defined as a `datetime`, so any values stored in `a` will be stored as a `datetime`. If you want to change the datatype of a column, `UPDATE` is the wrong type of statement. `UPDATE` is a DML statetment, where as to change a datatype you need to use a DDL statement; specifically you need to use `ALTER TABLE`. But, like I said, don't use a `varchar` to store a date. It's just a **bad** idea.

Answer (score 1):

A type like DATETIME isn't stored with a format.

So if one updates a DATETIME with a string in a certain format, it doesn't matter for the stored value in the DATETIME field.
The formatted string is implicitly converted to a datetime. At least if it's in a format that's valid.

The function FORMAT, which returns a NVARCHAR is rather used for representation of the datetime field in a query.
Or if one wants to INSERT/UPDATE a string field with a datetime in a certain format.  But that should be avoided, because it's much easier to work with a datetime than a string.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the output format of a datetime in the datetime itselfs.

If you need to output the datetime as formatted char/varchar, you need to use the convert-function when you select the data:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 101) -- format: MM/dd/yyyy
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 103) -- format: dd/MM/yyyy
```

In your case:

```
SELECT @DateMin AS a, CONVERT(char(10), @DateMin, 103) AS b
```

That works as expected.

If you want to have a mutable data-type, you need to declare it as sql_variant:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;
CREATE TABLE #t(DateMin sql_variant);
INSERT INTO #t VALUES ('2019-01-13T00:00:00')

UPDATE #t SET DateMin = FORMAT(CAST(DateMin AS datetime), 'dd''/''MM''/''yyyy');
SELECT * FROM #t;
```

Also, your format-expression needs to explicitly put the / into quotation marks, aka `'dd''/''MM''/''yyyy'`, otherwise sql-server replaces it with the date-separator specific to the current culture, which would be `.` in my case.

Just use convert with option 103 instead, it works on all versions of sql-server and it's probably faster.

Also, your insert-statement fails on some versions of sql-server, because iso-date-format is 
`2019-01-13T00:00:00` and not `2019-13-01 00:00:00`

Correct is:

```
INSERT INTO #t VALUES ('2019-01-13T00:00:00')
```

[image: SQL-server end of support]

Also

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;
```

is sql-server 2016+ only, otherwise you need

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t
```

And post sql-server 2005, you should use datetime2 instead of datetime. 
You shouldn't use datetime anymore, because datetime uses float, and as such is imprecise - if you insert an iso datetime value, it can do funny things because of the float-point-machine-epsilon, e.g. set it to the next day if you have 23:59:59.999, just as a scary example.

I advise you to [never use the sql_variant type](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/problems-caused-by-use-of-the-sql_variant-datatype). If you have a temp-table with defined columns, just create another column where you will write the char/varchar value to.

Comment: Or alternatively SELECT FORMAT(@DateMin,'dd/MM/yyyy'). I like it better from a readability standpoint, avoiding the magic numbers.

Comment: @Ludovic Aubert: The magic numbers can be looked up. Also, you're limiting yourself to sql-server 2012+ if you use format. Shouldn't be an issue anymore, but it used to be. Some customers of ours, for example, are phasing out SQL-server 2008R2 only at the start of 2020. That way, they can skip 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and go directly to 2019, ideally 2019 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change that format for the user use this:

```
set dateformat dmy;
```

By running this statement:

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS;
```

you will see your dateformat is ydm so you can alway back it up to that if this is not what you wanted :)